# HttpClient.GetAsStringAsync returns invalid result

Tags: c#, google-places-api, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to get a list of restaurants from the Google Places Api, using HttpClient.

This code gets a response with status OK:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(Location location)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await 
                    client.GetAsync(
                        $"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location={location.lat},{location.lng}&radius=500&types=food&key={apiKey}");
                return response;
            }
        }
```

And, pasting the same url into Postman gets me the JSON I want.
Example:

```
{
  "html_attributions": [],
  "next_page_token": "CoQC8QAAAHJGK9M9kkDpmZs3UdDzT5KnypEqb4fdMoXeUFO836ks9B-wyE2GWs3a4xbuH_NvbbsQFELL4DoMl9Q7q2f28_6XtKVS3V0xKbDEMAdczLcauQrf3vNE0cIprK2DYemtJMowngp9Wu_3WSRDrxoP2BiWJbsqYk5okWPnPp3PM4cBjdE3f5sFkV3LCKOwdSChXT7a-fmy6katMS30vdqT5Jr4V0X3XeaFGJQvVWgiyHXjJKIQZRtZKbxr9ovT-B4uezbtV2-8NDoUXAZO0R2eBkrCWPlW_p8nnVYGilHpvvTk1V9WbXQfwm09y2SODZghVOuX7ViwqfM_s-1HOWZGjrkSEKpA1NwbMuLrtGvxqrVnTjsaFNjbcDsEdX_JkwhkrAi2hBwPzXNU",
  "results": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "location": {
          "lat": 55.701531,
          "lng": 13.192277
        }
      },
      "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
      "id": "3af0d044d45cd8587d9a3522bc98a95d4f60c6a8",
      "name": "Restaurang Stäket",
      "opening_hours": {
        "open_now": false,
        "weekday_text": []
      },
      "photos": [
        {
          "height": 333,
          "html_attributions": [
            "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/107255944189419980694\">Restaurang Stäket</a>"
          ],
          "photo_reference": "CmRdAAAAvIl4I9qTovKy3a66JJ--SUePUSoP4vE54BBuf6YIzJkfEzWxEVnx6RdoPp7kQ1O5rm8w0gTVYatE5RJg5gc98S92g7pV7JqKQtGf_-ny1a3kAjBl7NO9qoI7AwLeXiW0EhB2BLJoKLHYWZozRi_FgfhMGhRDnPbNeAyi17Kt-anIZgOAY-7rRQ",
          "width": 331
        }
      ],
      "place_id": "ChIJfc06o8SXU0YRqQzS2ENuF84",
      "rating": 3.8,
      "reference": "CnRmAAAAb04Z5F5nUHFRqqOxKPgJ6gBzJ-sDq21h6VE4gSVIAIAk5SCNzBac6N8_U3ozbh5Re-eEmqhseFnxAwzZjUNRGYSTG85rvXe6EBXJjz3xFtLZhp-dzezLNUgm6znBewmLsEBea5jTCB8Lyd3y4kz3lBIQOXYJ96C2SITtKUYNffZDOhoU-wLLrXGXdXb-AYigiG6jqGPgp8s",
      "scope": "GOOGLE",
      "types": [
        "restaurant",
        "food",
        "point_of_interest",
        "establishment"
      ],
      "vicinity": "Stora Södergatan 6, Lund"
    }
    ],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

However, when trying to get a string representation of the content in the response like this:

```
public async Task<string> Get(Location location)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await 
                    client.GetAsync(
                        $"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location={location.lat},{location.lng}&radius=500&types=food&key={apiKey}");
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
```

I get this instead:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

If I inspect the response-object, the status code is still OK, so the API-request seems to be fine, but I can't figure out what's going wrong when I try to get the string.

Comment: "so the API-request seems to be fine" - no, really not. The JSON returned is showing a status of "INVALID_REQUEST" so presumably the request *is* invalid in some way...

Comment: As Google docs ( https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) says: INVALID_REQUEST generally indicates that a required query parameter (location or radius) is missing. Make sure that your `location={location.lat},{location.lng}` parses properly.

Comment: Ah yes, I thought the response would have an error status if there was something wrong with the request, but I was obviously wrong. Seems to be a culture related problem with parsing the location, I get commas as a decimal instead of periods. Thanks!